# How to host an Angular app inside .NET Core 3.1 WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, single-page-application

I want to provide my Angular app through the root route `/` and the REST API through `/api/*`. For the Angular routing I have to redirect all requests to /index.html except the requests for existing files (e.g. media files) and my API controller routes.

With the `Startup.cs` below it's close to be working:

- Opening http://localhost:5000 will return the index.html and the angular routing is working, that I get redirected to http://localhost:5000/home
- API calls are still working
- Existing CSS/JavaScript files are returned

The following is not working: Refreshing or opening directly http://localhost:5000/home will end up in a 404. I guess `/home` is not redirected to the index.html.
What I'm missing here?

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
      _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {        
      services.AddSpaStaticFiles(options =>
      {
        options.RootPath = "wwwroot";
      });

      services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      app.UseDefaultFiles();
      app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
      app.UseCors();
      app.UseSwagger();
      app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { /*...*/ });
      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your are missing one important thing for SPA hosting:

```cs
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
});
```

> Handles all requests from this point in the middleware chain by returning the default page for the Single Page Application (SPA).
>
> **This middleware should be placed late in the chain, so that other middleware for serving static files, MVC actions, etc., takes precedence.**
>
> - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaapplicationbuilderextensions.usespa

---

Update: If you only want to map a specific route to the index.html i.e. everything starting with `http://localhost/ui/` you can combine it with  `app.MapWhen`

```cs
app.MapWhen(
    context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/ui/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), 
    cfg => 
    {
        cfg.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Just wandering, is it possible to directly using CND url to host SPA in AspNetCore?

Comment: app.UseSpa is no longer supported in .NET 6

Comment: @GerardoBuenrostroGonzález well the extension method for that still exists for net6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaapplicationbuilderextensions.usespa?view=aspnetcore-6.0 do you have the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` version 6.0.0 installed?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but `app.UseSpa(...)` did not work as I guess I was missing some dependecies.

Alternativele you could add `endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");` in `app.UseEndpoints(..)`, which is part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` assembly.

So it would look like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
});
```

Source: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Jul/12/Handling-SPA-Fallback-Paths-in-a-Generic-ASPNET-Core-Server#server-side-navigation-of-client-side-routes

Comment: .net 6 does not support app.UseSpa but your answer worked.